# Control point for DLNA renderer and Minimserver library?

Tags: media, dlna

At home I've got a Raspberry Pi running Minimserver, with a 4 TB hard drive connected, as a music server. In the family room I have a Google Chromecast Audio hooked up to my old audio receiver (optical line-in) which has the good speakers & sub. With a control point on my tablet or phone – BubbleUPnP works well – I can cast my music collection to the family room stereo and enjoy great sound.

Just added to the family room this past year is an Intel NUC with Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 and a nice monitor.  Now I sit there sometimes, playing games or surfing the web or whatever.

Is there a good control point I can run on Ubuntu, to fulfill the same function as my tablet in this use-case? Just work as a control point?

I **don't** want Ubuntu to be the music server. The RasPi handles that job perfectly. To me it's good for the music server to be single-use. It does one thing, and does it well. That leaves the Ubuntu desktop free for me to play 0AD / Transport Tycoon or edit music files or upgrade to 20.04 LTS, break the server and reboot it and mess around with it, all while having zero impact on the family room music-delivery infrastructure.

I'm just looking for a **control point** on Ubuntu. It would connect to Minimserver running on the RasPi, browse the library and manage playlists, and send to the Chromecast Audio renderer. Is there something that would do this job?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late for you probably, but if anyone else stumbles upon this question - the answer is upplay. I use it on a 20.04 laptop to drive a couple ("group") of Jam renderer-speakers from a pi running minidlna.

http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/upplay

Comment: Yes, the answer is upplay.  :-)
I stumbled on upplay independently – and it does the job perfectly.
Also, the same developer's upmpdcli is great too.  Runs on the RasPi, and takes the Chromecast Audio out of the equation: lets me (with a Digi+ HAT) plug the optical output of the RasPi directly into the stereo receiver.  The perfect set of solutions.
Thanks!